# h2 text won't appear ontop video

Tags: html, css

The text wont display on-top of the video. 
I am basically wanting a title which i called Heading to display overlaid on the video. I have tried fiddling with z-index and it does not change, i did notice when I replace the video for an image the text worked, that was using different css code, I am assuming their is a problem with the css.

Please help me, THANK YOU.

CSS CODE:

```
.home-subheading {
font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: .5px; 
font-weight: 400;
color: #ccc; 
z-index:999!important;
}

.tp-banner .home-subheading {
line-height: 40px!important;
#home-revolution-slider  {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -99;

}
.hero {
position: fixed; 
z-index: -99;
top: 0;
bottom:  0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-size: cover; 
}
.content {
position: relative;
z-index: 3; 
background-color: #fff;
}
.home-heading,
.home-subheading,
.home-button {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999; 
text-align: center;
transform: translateY(0px);
/*-webkit-transition: 1s opacity ease-in-out;*/
}
.tp-loader.spinner1 {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url(../img/assets/rev-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
background-color: transparent;
box-shadow:  none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: -20px;
-webkit-animation: none;
animation: none;
border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

.tp-banner-container{
width:100%;
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin-top: 0;
z-index: -1;
} 
.tparrows.preview4:after {
background: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
}
.tp-caption a {
color: #fff;
padding: 9px 22px;
box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
-o-box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
margin: 0 7px 0 7px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tp-caption a:hover {
color: #fff;
}
.html5-video-container video {
width: 100%!important;
height: auto!important;
left: 0!important;
z-index: -99;

}

.tp-banner-video video{
min-width: 100%;
z-index: -3;
```

HTML CODE:

```
                            <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                        <video src="img/coding.mp4"  autoplay loop alt="video_typing_cover"  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="repeat"></video>

                            <!-- LAYERS -->

                                <!-- Home Heading -->
                                <div class="tp-caption sft"
                                    data-x="center"  
                                    data-y="260"
                                    data-speed="1200"
                                    data-start="1100"
                                    data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
                                    data-splitin="none"
                                    data-splitout="none"
                                    data-endspeed="300"
                                    style="z-index: 4; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space:normal;">
                                    <h2 class="home-heading op-1">Digital Hive</h2>
                                </div>

                            <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                            <div class="tp-caption tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo"
                                data-x="0"
                                data-y="0"
                                data-speed="1000"
                                data-start="1100"
                                data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                                data-elementdelay="0.01"
                                data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                                data-endspeed="1500"
                                data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"
                                data-autoplay="true"
                                data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false"
                                data-nextslideatend="true"
                                data-volume="mute" 
                                data-forceCover="1" 
                                data-aspectratio="16:9" 
                                data-forcerewind="on" 
                                style="z-index: 2;">
                                <video class="img-responsive" preload="none" 
                                poster='example'> 
                                <source src='img/coding.mp4' autoplay    type='video/mp4' />
                                </video>
                            </div>
```

Comment: in css missing close '}'. 

.tp-banner .home-subheading {
line-height: 40px!important;
#home-revolution-slider  {

Comment: So you are wanting me to create .tp-banner awith

Comment: I have added }, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like you have messed up your code, not sure but I think you are using some slider, Also I think there is a Class .hero which need to add on video, let me what should b final result. see z-index works once you add position:absolute.

Comment: how do i fix this lol? im confused and ive tried changing to absolute.. changing z-index and nothing changes

Comment: Why there is some extra html? Are you using revolution slider? Or you using it in some kind of cms like wordpress or independent html? Is your work is on server? Can I see this on web?

Comment: yes im uisng a revolution slider

Comment: and no no cms, just from notepad ++ , no wordpress or anything.